# Where is the error logfile for MariaDB under my Debian host?

Tags: logging, mariadb

```
root@technoluddites:/var/lib/mysql# find . -name \*.err
root@technoluddites:/var/lib/mysql# find / -name \*.err
/var/log/mail.err
root@technoluddites:/var/lib/mysql# uname -a
Linux technoluddites.org 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MariaDB usually logs errors to a .err file, but I'm having trouble locating the file.

How can I locate the MariaDB error log file on a Debian VM?

Comment: On the official site https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/ you have to look in your configuration.
Check this topic https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174533/mariadb-default-logs-location-log-error

Answer (score 0):

**MariaDB Server online:**

If your MariaDB server is running, check the location via SQL command:

```
mysql -e"SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_error'\G"
```

**MariaDB Server offline:**

If you server is not running, check if an error log file was specified in configuration files:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep "log-error"
```

If log-error has no value, error log will be stored in your data directory, which can be obtained by

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep "datadir"
```